# iTunes 12 on elementary OS?

Tags: software-installation, wine, playonlinux

Is it it possible, to use iTunes 12.3 decently with wine or something like that on elementary OS? I really need that Progam for synchronizing my mobile iDevices.

Answer (score 3):

As stated voer there at [WineHQ](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=1347) runs slightly bad on Linux. **Noise** as out-of-the-box media player has the feature to sync with iDevices, as far as I know. So give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Well... I have also tried severel times to make iTunes work and sadly it's kind of pointless. But I found a somewhat good solution I guess. If you need to sync your i devices than just make a virtual box running Windows or Mac and install iTunes in that. And you can even do seamless mode if you are really wanting that ;)